# Lingui map translated content not showing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, translation, vite, linguijs

I am using [Lingui](https://lingui.dev/index.html) for translation from English to Arabic. I am using an array of objects to display my content.  The issue I have is that the Arabic translation for the mapped array is not showing. The codes are in separate files.

```js
import { t } from "@lingui/macro";
export const Courses = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: t`Unlock the secrets of Open Science.`,
    description: t`A beginner-friendly course to introduce the concepts and practices of Open Science.`,
    icon: Github,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: t`Your Open Science Journey Begins Here.`,
    description: t`Learn the basics of Open Science and start your journey towards more open and transparent research and education.`,
    icon: JavaScript,
  },
];

 

{Courses.map(({ id, name, icon, description }) => (
            <div key={id} className="courses-section__container-course">
              <div className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content">
                <img
                  src={icon}
                  className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content-icon"
                  alt={`${name} icon`}
                />
              </div>
              <h3 className="courses-section__container-course__name">
             {name}
              </h3>
              <p className="courses-section__container-course__description">
                {description}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
```

`i18n.ts` file:

```js
import { i18n } from "@lingui/core";
import { en, ar} from "make-plural/plurals";

export const locales = {
  en: "English",
  ar: "Arabic",
};
export const defaultLocale = "en";

i18n.loadLocaleData({
  en: { plurals: en },
  ar: { plurals: ar },
});

i18n.load(defaultLocale, {});
i18n.activate(defaultLocale);

export async function dynamicActivate(locale: string) {
  const { messages } = await import(`./locales/${locale}/messages.ts`);
  i18n.load(locale, messages);
  i18n.activate(locale);
}
```

The `.linguirc` config

```json
{
  "locales": ["en", "ar"],
  "sourceLocale": "en",
  "catalogs": [{
    "path": "src/locales/{locale}/messages",
    "include": ["src"]
  }],
  "format": "minimal",
  "compileNamespace": "ts"
}
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the code that loads the translations, as the code you provided doesn't have any glaring issues

Comment: I have included the i18n.ts and linguric config files

Comment: It looks good as far as I can tell, the only reasons I can think of is 1. not running `lingui extract` and `lingui compile` 2. Not activating the locale (easy check is to rebuild with the default locale set to arabic) or 3. a caching issue/build path issue. (this is actually simpler than some of my designs with lingui)

Comment: There are other contents on the page and they perfectly displayed its Arabic text, it's only the mapped data that is not displaying the Arabic text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `t` macro gets executed before the locale is fully loaded (assuming that the descriptions, etc. are included as text to be translated by lingui).

The best option to do this would be:

```js
import { t } from "@lingui/macro";

export const Courses = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: () => t`Unlock the secrets of Open Science.`,
    description: () => t`A beginner-friendly course to introduce the concepts and practices of Open Science.`,
    icon: Github,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: () => t`Your Open Science Journey Begins Here.`,
    description: () => t`Learn the basics of Open Science and start your journey towards more open and transparent research and education.`,
    icon: JavaScript,
  },
];


{Courses.map(({ id, name, icon, description }) => (
  <div key={id} className="courses-section__container-course">
    <div className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content">
      <img
        src={icon}
        className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content-icon"
        alt={`${name} icon`}
      />
    </div>
    <h3 className="courses-section__container-course__name">
   {name()}
    </h3>
    <p className="courses-section__container-course__description">
      {description()}
    </p>
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `t` macro outside of function is not going to work. Solution proposed Elias Schablowski would work, but there is better solution

```
export const Courses = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: msg`Unlock the secrets of Open Science.`,
    description: msg`A beginner-friendly course to introduce the concepts and practices of Open Science.`,
    icon: Github,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: msg`Your Open Science Journey Begins Here.`,
    description: msg`Learn the basics of Open Science and start your journey towards more open and transparent research and education.`,
    icon: JavaScript,
  },
];


const {i18n} = useLingui();

{Courses.map(({ id, name, icon, description }) => (
  <div key={id} className="courses-section__container-course">
    <div className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content">
      <img
        src={icon}
        className="courses-section__container-course__icon-content-icon"
        alt={`${name} icon`}
      />
    </div>
    <h3 className="courses-section__container-course__name">
   {i18n._(name)}
    </h3>
    <p className="courses-section__container-course__description">
      {i18n._(description)}
    </p>
  </div>
))}
```

Docs: https://js-lingui-git-next-lingui.vercel.app/tutorials/react-patterns